# Why can't the Java compiler infer Iterable<String> from the constraints "Iterable<? extends CharSequence> and () -> (Iterator<String>)"?

Tags: java, lambda, language-lawyer, type-inference, jls

Background: I recently wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484655/outputting-array-of-object-to-csv-file-correctly-in-java-help/58484936#58484936) where I suggested writing the following code:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("PostgradStudent.csv"),
        Arrays.stream(PGstudentArray).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()),
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

After some thoughts, I went: "I don't actually need a list here, I just need an `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>`".
As `Stream<T>` has a method `Iterator<T> iterator()`, I then thought, well, that's easy:

```
Iterable<? extends CharSequence> iterable = () -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::toString).iterator();
```

(I extracted it to a local variable for this question, I would like to do it inline at the end.)
Unfortunately this does not compile without additional type hints:

```
error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
Iterable<? extends CharSequence> iterable = () -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::toString).iterator();
                                                                                                   ^
    Iterator<String> cannot be converted to Iterator<CharSequence>
```

Of course adding some type hints will make this work:

```
Iterable<? extends CharSequence> iterable2 = (Iterable<String>) () -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::toString).iterator();
Iterable<? extends CharSequence> iterable3 = () -> Arrays.stream(arr).<CharSequence>map(Object::toString).iterator();
```

In my understanding, the Java compiler does the following things:

1. It looks at the target type of the expression, which is `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>`.
2. It then determines the function type of this interface, which is `() -> Iterator<? extends CharSequence>` in my case.
3. It then looks at the lambda and checks whether it is compatible.
   In my case, the lambda has a type of `() -> Iterator<String>`.
   Which is compatible with the function type determined in step 2.

Interestingly, if I change the target of the lambda to `Supplier`:

```
Supplier<Iterator<? extends CharSequence>> supplier = () -> Arrays.stream(arr)
    .map(Object::toString)
    .iterator();
```

it will compile fine.

Why can't javac infer the correct type for this lambda?

Comment: It should be `Iterable<? extends String>` Not `? extends CharSequence`

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I don't understand your comment. Look at the [Javadoc for Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-). This is not something I can change. And because `String` is final, it would be equal to `Iterable<String>`.

Comment: Might just be related to the [Capture Conversion#jls-5.1.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)

Comment: @Naman not at all. It doesn't matter if I use it as part of an assignment or if I use it in a call to `Files.write`. Assignment is just an easy way to provide a target for the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

You can find some explanation [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8025073):

> Wildcard-parameterized functional interface types must be turned into a function type (method signature) before checking for compatibility ... This works as follows:

```
Iterable<? extends CharSequence> becomes () -> Iterator<CharSequence>
```

So, if the lambda expression is implicitly-typed, the LHS becomes `Iterator<CharSequence>` while the RHS is `Iterator<String>`. Hence, an error:

```
Iterator<String> cannot be converted to Iterator<CharSequence>
```

This behavior is also explained in the [JLS §18.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.3).

Comment: Interesting fact is that `Supplier<Iterator<? extends CharSequence>>` as target works just fine. What is the difference here?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You added one more level of nesting which doesn't have a wildcard.

Comment: So basically, because the parameter `Iterator<? extends CharSequence>` is not a wildcard, it doesn't do that? Then why not do that one level above as well?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn That's a question for the language designers.

Comment: So, to summarize, to avoid a hard technical problem (type inference is hard), they decided to cheat a bit (which is fine), but they did it in a way that does not avoid this problem in all cases (which is stupid)?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn If you'd like to dive deeper into this topic - check the JLS section which describes how does the [**function type**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9) is defined.

Comment: @OleksandrPyrohov this... makes no sense to me. `LHS` becomes `Iterator<CharSequence>`, let's suppose this is true; then how come a cast of the `RHS` (`(Iterable<String>)`...) makes it work? It should generate the same exact error.

Comment: @Eugene Citation from the linked bug: *We make some extra effort to choose a better function type when an explicitly-typed lambda expression is being used ...* - in case of explicitly-typed lambda expression the process is different.

Comment: @OleksandrPyrohov right, I have read that. nevertheless, it does not make it less weird to me. your answer _is_ spot-on, no doubt, it's just me not completely satisfied.

Comment: @Eugene Thank you, I completely understand you! I will also add a little clarification about the type of the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the other answer (which is absolutely correct) and some coffee, it seems the explanation in the bug is pretty logical.

There are two cases here: an *explicit* lambda type and an *implicit* lambda type. The explicit type is :

```
Iterable<String> one = () -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::toString).iterator();
Iterable<? extends CharSequence> iterable = one;
```

or as in the OP's example:

```
Iterable<? extends CharSequence> iterable2 = (Iterable<String>) () -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::toString).iterator();
```

We are directly telling to the compiler which type the lambda expression is : `Iterable<String>`.

In this case the compiler has one thing to do only: see if the target is assignable to that type; pretty easy to find out and not very much related to lambdas per-se.

The other type is an *implicit* type, when the compiler has to *infer* the type and things get a bit tricky here. The "tricky" part comes from the fact that the target uses wildcards, thus could match more than just one option. There could be an infinite number of ways (finite of course, but just to prove a point) that the lambda could be inferred as.

It could start with something like this for example:

```
Iterator<? extends Serializable> iter = Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::toString).iterator();
```

No matter what further gets done, this will fail: `CharSequence` does not extend `Serializable`, but `String` does; we will not be able to assign `Iterable<? extends CharSequence> iterable` to "whatever-the-infered-type-with-Serializable-is".

Or it could start with:

```
Iterator<? extends Comparable<? extends CharSequence>> iter = Arrays.stream(arr).map(Object::toString).iterator();
```

So theoretically the compiler could just start to infer what that type could be and check one by one if a "certain" inferred type could match the target; but requires a lot of work, obviously; thus not done.

The other way is a lot easier, "cut" the target and thus drop the possibilities of inference to just one. Once the target is transformed to:

```
Iterable<CharSequence> iterable...
```

the work that a compiler has to do is *far* more simple.

This, btw, would not be the first time I see this implicit vs explicit types logic in lambdas.

Comment: And how does this work with `Supplier<Iterator<? extends CharSequence>>`?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn this has to do with _nested_ wildcards, I am still trying to figure out what is going on, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902219/nested-wildcards/58631449#58631449) is a recent answer I've posted related to this.